# DataGrid's rows appear minisized when the application is run

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, height, row

I've created following DataGrid design:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:leartWPF" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="leartWPF.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window1"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:GroupDataSource x:Key="GroupDataSourceDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupCellTemplete" >
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding }" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupDataSourceDataSource}}">
        <DataGrid  Margin="0" HeadersVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Groups" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource GroupCellTemplete}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

which in ExpressionBlend looks like this:

[image]

however, when I run the application, It looks like this:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGrid.RowHeight = double.NaN;
```

Comment: any idea on how do I set this in XAML?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2113127/114029 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6796120/114029

Comment: Thanks. One more question: the app now displays the cells as empty instead displaying the contents even though I set {Binding Path=.} in <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=.}" />. I'm trying to bind the datagrid to list of strings. Would you know what's wrong with that?